# Conda build environment variables not set during build

Tags: python, powershell, environment-variables, conda, conda-build

Conda build fails to set some build environment variables during the build process.

During build I get the following error message

```
%SRC_DIR%>et "CONDA_BUILD=1"
'et' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Inspecting the `build_env_setup.bat` (temporary file in build work folder) it is suppose to `set "CONDA_BUILD=1"`.

That is, it has somehow lost the `s` from `set`. This happens for roughly half of the `set` calls in the `build_env_setup.bat`.

I have tried building on another Windows machine and (using the equivalent `build.sh`) on Debian (wsl) and it works. So it seems to be an error on *my* machine. Uninstall + install Miniconda did nothing.

What can cause this error and how may I resolve it?

**Update / Extra Info**

- This behavior is observed using PowerShell 7.1.3. When using CMD all the variables *are* set.
- The generated `build_env_setup.bat` has Unix style line-endings (LF) changing to CRLF make the `build_env_setup.bat` script work.
- There is a Ø in one of the paths set (on my system) removing that line also makes the (remaining) `build_env_setup.bat` script work.

Conclusion seems to be that there is some string encoding / reading mismatch when running the various build scrips using PowerShell in the (edge?) cases with special characters in paths.

---

**Old formulation**

I am attempting to build a conda package from a standard src-layout python library but my builds keeps failing when using a Windows build script `bld.bat` with the error message:

```
'(_h_env)%SRC_DIR%>"" setup.py install
'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This seems to indicate that the `%PYTHON%` environment variable is not defined. (Which I was assuming to exist based on [Environment variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html) and [Writing the build script files](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html#writing-the-build-script-files-build-sh-and-bld-bat))

If I add a `build` section to the `meta.yaml`:

```
build:
  noarch: python
  script: "{{ PYTHON }} setup.py install"
```

Then the build works.

What is the reason for this behavior and where is the error when using the build script?

### Setup

- OS: Windows 10
- conda: 4.13.0
- conda-build: 3.21.9
- python: 3.10.4

### Folders and files

```
│   setup.py
│
├───conda_recipe
│       bld.bat
│       meta.yaml
│
└───src
    └───conda_build_test
            module.py
            __init__.py
```

#### bld.bat

```
"%PYTHON%" setup.py install
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

#### meta.yaml

```
package:
  name: conda_build_test
  version: {{ data.get('version') }}

source:
  path: ..

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python
```

Comment: Weird. Sounds like it's failing while trying to activate the build environment. Maybe try running with verbosity turned up (`-v` or `-vv`). Given you reinstalled, unlikely it's a corrupt install, but possibly the setup of `conda init powershell` is awry. Perhaps try `conda init --reverse`, then `conda init powershell` to rerun the configuration. This is something that could be residual, despite reinstallation. You can also use `-d` and `-vv` flags to preview the changes.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that [the documentation on environment variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-set-during-the-build-process) states that `%PYTHON%` is only defined when `python` is specified as a **host** requirement (e.g., in a cross-compiling situation). In a native build situation, where `python` is directly in the **build** requirements, the build environment's `bin/` will be on PATH and one can use `python` directly. That is,

**bld.bat**

```batch
python %SRC_DIR%/setup.py install
```

For a comparable example, [the Conda Forge `multineat` feedstock recipe](https://github.com/conda-forge/multineat-feedstock/tree/main/recipe) uses a `setup.py`-based build.

Alternatively, you can place the `python` requirement under **host** instead of **build** and that should enable use of `%PYTHON%` variable.

I'm not entirely clear on why there isn't a failure after the `meta.yaml` edit. Somehow the `{{ PYTHON }}` jinja template must not be the same as the environment variable. However, the examples on Conda Forge I find that use a similar `{{ PYTHON }} setup.py install` seem to also list `python` as a **host** requirement (e.g., [`wfdb` feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/wfdb-feedstock/blob/main/recipe/meta.yaml)).

Comment: Excellent, thanks for pointing that out! 

However conda build still fails to set the SRC_DIR variable. I have updated the question with extra info.